# How to use macro inside TikZ decoration options

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-decorations

I would like to set the decoration options for an edge by using a macro, like this:

```
\def\curlbl{text along path,text={hi}}
\newcommand{\myedge}[2]{%
 \path (#1) edge[decorate, decoration={\curlbl}] (#2);
}
```

However, this does not work as I intended and I get an error I do not understand:

```
./minimal.tex:12: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/\pgfkeyscurrentname ' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Here is my tex file:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\def\curlbl{text along path,text={hi}}
\newcommand{\myedge}[2]{%
 \path (#1) edge[decorate, decoration={\curlbl}] (#2);%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) {\emph{A}};
  \node[below left=10ex and 6ex of A] (B) {\emph{B}};
  \myedge{A}{B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to use a macro to set the options of a TikZ `decoration`?

Comment: Why do you want to use a `LaTeX` macro when you can do it with `TikZ` without a macro?

Comment: @AndréC I want to conditionally set the macro with an `\ifthenelse`.

Comment: In my humble opinion, it would be better to pose the problem with a conditional macro. But now, since there is already an answer, it is no longer useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a so-called expansion problem: when Ti*k*Z parses the path, your macro is not yet expanded. Of course, the problem can of course be solved in various way. An arguably rather elegant way, provided you insist on the overall strategy here to use a macro in this way, is to tell Ti*k*Z to expand `\curlbl`. This can be accomplished by using the `.expanded` key.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\def\curlbl{text along path,text={hi}}
\newcommand{\myedge}[2]{%
 \path (#1) edge[decorate, decoration/.expanded={\curlbl}] (#2);%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) {\emph{A}};
  \node[below left=10ex and 6ex of A] (B) {\emph{B}};
  \myedge{A}{B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I strongly suspect that, if you provide us with the full picture, there will be a more Ti*k*Zy way to achieve that. Without knowing the details, at this point I can only draw your attention to the keys `is if` and `is choice`, which are described on p. 889 of the pgfmanual.

Comment: Hm, before posting this question I tried putting `\edef` infront of `\curlbl`, but that did not work. The real reason I want this is for conditionally setting some decoration options in the macro.

Do you know a good place where I can read about how to I should use `edef`? I am new to this latex macro business :)

Comment: My own failed attempt was to use `decoration={\edef\curlbl}`.  I tried to reduce my problem down to the minimal reproducible example. Your solution seems to work for conditionally changing the decoration - I simply have an extra `\ifthenelse{}` to conditionally define `\curlbl`.

Comment: @user11171 Meanwhile I added a slightly more Ti*k*Zy way that just uses `./expanded`. Cold you please add the full ifthenelse thingy to your question? Otherwise there might be miscommunication because I do not really understand yet what you want to achieve.